# Can we have an ADHD Stack Overflow version?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, hot-questions

First off, hide the hot network questions. I should be learning how to fix a JavaScript error, not why [Darth Vader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darth_Vader) didn't talk with [R2-D2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R2-D2) for a long time. It turns out he actually didn't have the opportunity, such a shame. If only they had Facebook profiles...

Every time you enter the website, it will ask for tags. Then it will hide all the other way more interesting questions than the one you're looking for. Instead, it will only display the questions with the tag you selected. Even then, some questions that have nothing to do with my issue would pop up. So, everytime I click on a question, an option dialog should pop up:

"You have a deadline and you need to fix this issue. Is this question related to your problem? If not, get out of here, you'll end up unemployed and eventually living on the streets"

With the options:

"Thanks, I don't want to be a hobo."
"It's a risk I'm willing to take."

Also, remove the Stack Exchange selection box in the top left corner. There's way more interesting stuff I couldn't give 2 flying fs about, like [Parenting](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/tour), [Poker](https://poker.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Aviation](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/tour). Also, have you seen that section, Ask Parents? I realized it's actually [Ask Patents](https://patents.stackexchange.com/users/603/peter-mortensen), I may be a little dyslexic too after all.

Similar questions are often distracting too, specially when they're not similar at all but way more interesting.

Comment: How about you install a website blocker, one you cannot override, but with a timeout, instead? *Block Stack Overflow for 8 hours*.

Comment: Otherwise, use a user stylesheet; with a little CSS knowledge you can hide just about anything on the site.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I could, but I need it.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Wouldn't I be lazy if I just asked the question instead of searching for an existing answer? I'm trying not to pollute the place with more repeated questions.

Comment: @ComicSansMSLover: Google does an excellent cached view; search, click the little down-arrow, pick 'cached copy'. Done.

Comment: `There's way more interesting stuff I couldn't give 2 flying fs about` Isn't that a contradiction?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Dude it's so hard, you have no idea. I just did this to test your suggestion, so I randomly googled, aaaaaa. First link showed this: http://store.steampowered.com/app/15520/ - Now I'm tempted to know more about the game and waste money on it.

Comment: @DavidRobinson Oh yeh, substitute couldn't for shouldn't.

Comment: @ComicSansMSLover: hint: use `site:stackoverflow.com` to limit your search. Another hint: go get the game, it'll keep you busy rather than come here. Problem solved in a different way.

Comment: @MartijnPieters But I can play and come here simultaneously. I already limit my search, it's just not enough.

Comment: To be honest, I did hide "hot network questions" with Greasemonkey, and it helped me :)

Comment: @legoscia I'll actually try this.

Comment: Seems to me Meta is already adopted as a place for the ADHD challenged to vent their frustrations.

Comment: Am I the only one who doesn't get how the title matches the content here?

Comment: @DanubianSailor - I think the idea is that the version of Stack Overflow the OP is suggesting would benefit those with ADHD by eliminating distractions.

Comment: Use the mobile site, linked in the footer, next to "contact us".

Comment: +44, -52, so quite a few people agree they are distracting, and some want to be distracted at work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Feature Request: \[Focus\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345120/feature-request-focus)

Answer (score 18):

> First off, hide the hot network questions.

That's easy to do yourself. Use any ad blocker or similar tool you want which works with your particular web browser of choice, and hide the `<div>` that has `id="hot-network-question"`. Poof, hot network questions are now gone from your view, and you can focus on what you need to do. [Here is one way to do it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223603/157730), with a tip of the proverbial hat to [Nikana Reklawyks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1449460/nikana-reklawyks).

As for Stack Exchange paying developers to implement something like a checkbox somewhere to do this, I'm doubtful. It has a very easy workaround, and there are [many features which can be considered more important](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request?sort=votes) based on community voting.

> Everytime you enter the website, it will ask for tags. Then it will hide all the other way more interesting questions than the one you're looking for.

Start out at [the blank Search page](https://stackoverflow.com/search), and you'll be forced to be specific about what you want to see.

Comment: I always use this search function, only search for accepted question, etc, etc.

Still, in the end, when I click a question, I just end up in the same place I started, with a lot of distractions.

I just think that hiding hot network questions should be an option. I mean, this section is like those news websites sections where they want to make you click more and more by using pretentious headlines and shock images.

Comment: Look at this: http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/9035/dragons-and-aviation-bureaucracy

What the hell, this is so interesting, I can't help it.

Comment: @ComicSansMSLover You can hide the hot network questions list already if you want to; I told you in the answer how to do that. While a checkbox might be a nice addition, for something with such a simple workaround it's at best going to be **far** down on the list of priorities for the Stack Exchange developers.

Comment: Yeh, I know you did, and I will do it. Just asking if there's a chance we could have an option do hide it.

Comment: [Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222721/how-to-avoid-hot-network-questions-on-the-sidebar?lq=1)  gives a howto for Adblock - add the following filter: `stackoverflow.com###hot-network-questions`

Comment: @NikanaReklawyks Nice find, thank you. Incorporated.

Comment: I like your comment about the addblocker.   I did and it works peachy.  But I dislike your opinion.   Google won in part because they realized their purpose was not to distract people but to get them what they need.  The hot network questions is distracting internal advertising.

Comment: I would like to be able to toggle HNQ on and off in the site and have it remember the preference for my account. I use a number of machines, some with higher security requirements, so installing ad blockers is not an ideal solution.

Comment: It doesn't matter what's easy and what isn't easy. OP is at -11, -12 when I arrived, and his point is legitimate. He's trying to fix JavaScript issues and being distracted by questions about R2-D2.

Installing an extension, although easy, doesn't defeat the silly ideology behind a sidebar full of distractions for a website designed mainly to help people be productive.

Answer (score 10):

Sounds like a great use for [the API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs)!

Yes, I realize I'm suggesting a massive distraction to someone who wishes to be distracted *less often*. Sorry. But, if you come up with something good, you can [share it with others who might be facing the same problem.](https://stackapps.com/)

Comment: Why would you link to an entire API document without specifically mentioning which API calls you find relevant?

Answer (score 10):

I struggle with Stack Exchange distraction too, more often than I'd like to admit. Neither turning off the internet altogether, nor anything that blocks Stack Overflow, are viable solutions, because I frequently need to look things up while working, and too much of the useful info is here.

I need inbound Google links, on-site search links, and often "related question" links to work. Links that should be closed off are anything on Meta, the homepage, and pretty much anything on the rest of the network except Programmers and the occasional Unix and CompSci post. Especially important is to block *my favorite tag pages* (i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/objc).

I recently discovered a free tool that lets me do this. It's a web proxy that I run locally, called [Privoxy](https://www.privoxy.org).

It has a wide variety of features and is preconfigured mostly to deal with ads, but the key for me is its nice flexible URL matching, combined with its "block" action.

In [its user.action config file](https://www.privoxy.org/user-manual/actions-file.html#AEN4852), I put this:

```
{ +block{Get back to work.} }
# No home page
stackoverflow.com/$
# No tag lists
.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/
# No Meta
meta.stackoverflow.com
# Nothing at all on other sites, with exceptions below
.stackexchange.com
news.ycombinator.com

{ -block{Allow access to search results} }
programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/
cs.stackexchange.com/questions/
unix.stackexchange.com/questions/
```

And that keeps me on the straight and narrow.