# Is it a good idea to disable 'Hot Network Questions' to boost productivity?

Tags: feature-request, hot-questions

I'm using Stack Overflow to get stuff done, not when looking for entertainment.

The **Hot Network Questions** list is interesting, and entertaining, but it doesn't get me closer to getting stuff done.

That is why in every browser I have ad-blocker installed, and I add a custom rule to block `#hot-network-questions`.

Would you consider adding option to disable **Hot Network Questions** somewhere in profile settings?

You can call it *no distraction mode*. You can also search for "google pacman cost" to see what I mean.

*(No distractions, getting stuff done, currently using adblocker, please consider adding option in the UI)*

---

Other people have requested the same:

- [Can we have an ADHD Stack Overflow version?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284350/can-we-have-an-adhd-stackoverflow-version)
- [How to avoid "Hot Network Questions" on the sidebar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222721/how-to-avoid-hot-network-questions-on-the-sidebar/223603)

Approximately 1/3 of the community upvotes such proposals. For now I'm just installing ad-blocker specifically for that reason.

Comment: WOW... 3 downvotes in 8 minutes... I need to ask better questions :) ```is it good idea``` - I would imagine that downvote means **NO**?

Comment: Yes, downvotes in meta work differently and express agreement/disagreement and not correctness or usefulness. Don't worry about it - it's not personal people just don't want the feature.

Comment: What productivity are you talking about? Will this raise our paychecks?

Comment: Your post is really funny(silently laughing at myself in the office). Everyone works and I read this post about productivity :)

Comment: @brasofilo - I hear you :) I have some work ethics standards... *(but that's a longer conversation)*

Comment: What is by the way the recent trend to close discussion questions as opinion-based?

Comment: I believe the proper term is "pure cussedness" (I've reopened)

Comment: @Shog9: And I propose re-closing (though as dupe).

Comment: I just blocked them. Ask me in a month how it went.

Comment: Can moderator remove my name from the question? I hate when there are ___ revisions and the question does not resemble my style.

Comment: Yes, it is a great idea!

Comment: @Chloe how did it go ?

Comment: @beppe9000 It is great. I block them on my desktop and I can focus only on the question I'm looking at. I currently do not block them on my work laptop and I have just wasted 2.5 hours on the hot network questions completely unrelated to why I came here in the first place. However, I did learn some things, so there's that.

Comment: @Chloe now I am blocking them :)  In the future I will make some userscript to get the best of both worlds (either time-based blocking or some ui that is collapsed by default)

Answer (score 2):

Then they should remove the logo as well, as when you click it you get an endless list of questions that need answering, editing and moderating.

So, no.

You need discipline.

Comment: My operating system explicitly refuses to deal with sarcasm, irony and rhetorical questions. Therefore I'm unable to respond to suggestion to ```remove the logo```

Comment: I'm neither being sarcastic nor ironic. I am advocating a slippery slope argument though. The site has _plenty_ of distractions, so when your suggestion should be considered, where should it stop?

Comment: On the sites I moderate, I find the biggest distraction to be regular users. Can I disable them? Even if only for an hour? Please?

Comment: @Yannis yeah those pesky people with their elaborate answers full of knowledge to absorb and links to external resources to read ... take up all my time! Ban them! I am being ironic now, though.

Comment: ```You need discipline``` - I agree... You can find a lot of information why Barrack Obama and Steve Jobs were wearing same clothes everyday. Less decisions - less fatigue - more bandwidth for making decisions when it actually matters. Whenever I can I choose not to think - that is why using ad blocker... 1 hour on meta and ```+5``` and ```-10``` - does it mean than ```1/3``` of the public wants that feature?

Comment: @Michal voting in general, but on meta specifically, is _weird_. You may be right in that 1/3rd of the people who bothered to vote agree with you though.

Comment: @Yannis: "Can I disable [users]?" The unintentional offensiveness of this statement is incredibly amusing.

Answer (score 0):

No, the opinion of the community of Stack Overflow is that its members are responsible people. If you can't be responsible it's not Stack Overflow's place to discipline you.

If you don't want to view the hot network questions - you can use readability mode which is something a lot of browsers offer for example [this chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/readability/oknpjjbmpnndlpmnhmekjpocelpnlfdi?hl=en).

Comment: I mentioned twice in my question that I use ad blocker so readability mode is not required really.

Comment: @MichalStefanow but readability mode solves the _more general issue_ - blocking a specific selector only solves it in one place for one site.

Comment: There's also the mobile view (mobile link in the footer). Way less clutter than the full site view...