# Feature Request: [Focus]

Tags: feature-request

I doubt Stack Exchange Inc. would ever go for this... 
But I'm going to let it fly, because I know that it would improve my UX on across the platform and I'm not singular here:

> Focus! It's hard for everybody, but especially hard for me. When reading a question on Stack Exchange I find it difficult to concentrate on the question and answer, especially if it's computer code.

## WHAT IF?

> we could click an ***optional*** button that toggled the screen somewhat analogous to
>   "presentation mode"...

- Just the Question
- **(split screen)**
- Just the Answer -> click "next", to view next answer, like a slide deck
- White Background
- (I'd even accept a text ad)

### ***that's it***

The page is too busy to concentrate.

Comment: I'm certain that this idea has been pitched (and likely shot down) before...but the main concern I have with this is that it represents a smaller subset of the community.  If this is a problem for you, do you have this problem on other websites, and how do you mitigate it?

Comment: What if you need to refer back to the question while writing your answer? What if the question gets edited *while* you're writing your answer?

Comment: @makato I know it's been shot down.  I'm tossing it back up. 

Stylebot is how I mitigate it.

Comment: @BoltClock split screen?

Comment: Alternatively, Export to text editor ->

Comment: *Innotvate*.  That is the most awesome spelling mistake I've seen in a long time.  Generally useful, but so descriptive of the proposal as well.  I see a big opportunity to use it in my own work, thanks!

Comment: I sometimes use the [Reader View](https://support.mozilla.org/t5/Basic-Browsing/Firefox-Reader-View-for-clutter-free-web-pages/ta-p/38466) in Firefox.

Comment: No one's ever full-screened a YouTube video? Esc key! All the extraneous options and navigation comes right back!

Comment: @Zach_is_my_name "Alternatively, Export to text editor" -- One lossless way of doing that right now is clicking edit, then clicking on the main textbox, then Ctrl-A and Ctrl-C.

Answer (score 3):

It isn't a terrible idea in general, although to be honest you *really* must do your research if you are going to convince a team of engineers to implement your proposal.

The approach of using a more visually pleasing browsing experience is one that I have considered trying with a userscript before. Basically it used the review framework to navigate new questions; I realize this is different, but it has the same flaw.

Stack Overflow is not an entertainment website. It does not need to have parallax, `<marquee>`, or any other visually pleasing elements *at all*. This is because the vast majority of users coming to Stack Overflow are the ones seeking knowledge, and they do not care what the frame around that information looks like. Frankly, neither do I.

While I attempt to give back to the Stack Overflow community, my primary use of the site is to stand on the shoulders of giants while developing a project - which is what most unregistered users from google are trying to do as well.

Here is an answer that I found rather helpful today: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6423891/1026459 while working with a view. I am really thrilled that while trying to find the solution to the problem I was working on, the pages loaded in less than a second as it can often take several attempts to find the right post.

Overall, the feature being requested here is over engineering - not to mention Stack Overflow wouldn't even use `border-radius` for a long time as it was seen as excessive.  Moreover, there really needs to be a lot more citation for a feature which would change the *entire* front facing aspect of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Agree on some points but not all, because I think this vision is misunderstood. First, the most interesting assertion is that I would most likely increase page load time. But how this proposal could be views as flashy "entertainment" I don't know. Imagine if you had all of these current page elements in your editor as you're working... the idea is to isolate the parts you're concerned with by clicking a button. Bring it back with another click. Sometimes I think people (not you obviously) reject an idea because it brings change, even positive, with no drawback, and because it is not their own

Comment: @Zach_is_my_name: "*Sometimes I think people (not you obviously) reject an idea because it brings change, even positive, with no drawback, and because it is not their own*" FYI: The fastest way to get people to ignore *everything* you say is to declare that you are so right that everyone who thinks you're wrong secretly agrees with you and is just denying the truth of your claims because they're jealous.

Comment: @NicolBolas Agreed.  I got frustrated and switched to honesty mode

Comment: @NicolBolas and in fairness it's nearly impossible to sell an idea to a community with which you have relatively zero reputation. Incidently, i have no stake in either